# How can I find the time at which the diode charges the capacitor every cycle(half wave rectifier)

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rectifier

[image]

Half wave rectifier is given and given values are :

V_p = 10V, V_d = 0.7V, 1/T = 60Hz, R = 10.

I want to know when C = 0.1F, how can I find the time at which the diode charges the capacitor every cycle.

I failed to approach this problem because I'm not sure at which parameter I should find out. I'm understanding capacitor charging time is T, but I don't think T=1/60 is answer.

I tried so far on this :

$$i_{DMAX} = \frac{V_p-V_d}{R} + C\cdot V_p\cdot \frac{2\pi}{T}\sqrt{\frac{2V_R}{V_p}} = 65.02A$$

$$ dv/dt = V_P\cdot  \omega \cos(\omega t)$$

---redo---

Now I find when charging time is \$ \Delta T\$

$$v_0(T-\Delta T) = V_p-V_d-V_r$$

and

$$V_r =\frac{(V_p-V_d)T}{RC}$$

$$v_0(T-\Delta T) = V_pcos(\frac{2\pi}{T}\Delta T)-V_D$$

Comment: What have  you tried so far on this?

Comment: Please show all of your work and ask a more specific question. This is not Chegg, we won't do your homework for you.

Comment: I failed to approach this problem because I'm not sure at which parameter I should find out. I'm understanding capacitor charging time is T, but I don't think T=1/60 is answer.

Comment: The capacitor start be charging when \$ v_s \$ is \$ v_d \$ above the output voltage and stop when it falls below this  voltage.  Without effort on your part we can't do homework for you.

Comment: I edited some of the questions, sorry for ambiguous posting.

Comment: @WarrenHill I understand now initially capacitor is charged until V_p-V_d by source, and  v_s begins lower, diode get reverse biased, v_o only get linear declination by ripple voltage. And when diode get forward-biased again capacitor starts charging and ends when v_s=V_p

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Wrong answer]
the capacitor never charges completely, we often calculate the time at which the capacitor will charge to 63% of Vs

First have the charging formula:

\begin{eqnarray*}
V(t)=V1(1- e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})
\end{eqnarray*}

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8ltRg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\begin{equation}
V(RC)=V1(1- e^{-1})= 0.63\times V1\\
\end{equation}

So now you have your time constant in seconds which is: RC

you still must verifiy a condition on RC, it should be smaller than the priod of your signal

Comment: Since the OP is talking about 60Hz it's a sinusoidal input not DC.  Also your formula is for a series resistor, not parallel.

Comment: The formula is just to show the equation, I know he's asking about AC
why the formula is not for parallel?

Comment: The capacitor charges via the diode and not via the resistor. I suggest you quickly remove this post to save face.

Comment: With your circuit when you close the switch the R you need to use is that of the switch not the one you have drawn.  The capacitor will charge very quickly.

Comment: Yes yes now I can see what you mean
thank you for clarifications

Comment: I downvoted it because there is no series resistor. In practical cases, there may be some.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the infos